# Suppose $T:V\to U$ is linear and $u\in U.$ Prove that either $u\in \text{Im}(T)$ or $\exists \phi\in V^*$ such that $T^t(\phi)=0$ and $\phi(u)=1.$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose  $T:V\to U$ is linear and $u\in U.$ Prove that either $u\in \text{Im}(T)$ or $\exists \phi\in V^*$ such that $T^t(\phi)=0$ and $\phi(u)=1.$

I am a little confused regarding this problem. We know that any linear functional $\phi: V\to \mathbb{K}$.  How can $\phi$ take values from $U$, that is how can we talk about $\phi(u)$ when $u\not \in V$?

Suppose it was a typo with $U^*$ instead of $V^*,$ then this is my attempt: 
$\newcommand{\I}{\text{Im}}$
Suppose $u\not \in \I(T)$ then define $\phi(u)=1$ and $0$ otherwise. Then this linear functional $\phi\in U^*$ works. If for all $\phi\in U^*$ we had that $T^t(\phi)\not =0$ or $\phi(u)\not =1$ then we will argue that $u\in \I(t).$ For that we need $v\in V$ such that $u=T(v).$ Now if we assume that $\phi\circ T\not =0$ and so there exists $x\in V$ such that $\phi(T(x))=a\not =0.$ How do I proceed?

[image]

Comment: Make some order between your $\;W\;$ and your $\;U\;$ ...and also decide whether $\;\phi\in V^*\;$ , as you wrote, or else $\;\phi\in U^*\;$ ...as you wrote, btw, it makes not much sense. Also define what does $\;T^t(\phi)\;$ is supposed to be...some transpose?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: I see...and I cannot solve your problem: either it is $\;T:V\to V\;$ and there is no $\;U\;$ separately, or else it is $\;u\in V\;$ and then it can't be $\;u\in Im\,T\;$ ....I don't know, really.

Comment: I have added the original problem picture, maybe that clears some issues.

Comment: Can you tell me the source text?

Comment: Schaum's Outline of Theory of Linear Algebra Problem 11.36, Page 375 chapter 11

Comment: Haven't you proven the required statement by constructing your $\phi$? I fail to understand what you've tried after that.

Comment: So the thing is that we have to show that $X$ is true or $Y$ is true. I have shown that if $X$ is false then $Y$ must be true. But I must also show that if $Y$ is false then $X$ is true.

Comment: It seems to be a typo. I think your proof is fine. Assume $u\notin Im\left(T\right)$. Let $\phi$ be as defined. Then
$T^{t}\left(\phi\right)\left(v\right)=\phi\left(Tv\right)=0$ for
all $v\in V$, i.e., $T^{t}\left(\phi\right)=0$.

Comment: No, you needn't show the other case. Essentially your proof boils down 2 things. (X = True) or (Y = True) iff (X = True) or (X = false $\implies$ Y = True). Which you have successfully done.

Comment: @SuperMario I can't understand how you succeeded to proved whatever: the problem, as it is, has an essential flaw as $\;\phi\in V^*\implies \phi:V\to\Bbb F\;$ is a linear functional. Thus, $\;\phi\;$ applies on elements **of the space** $\;V\;$ and not on those of the space $\;U\;$ . You also must make clear what Lipschutz means in that book by $\;T^t(\phi)\;$ , though I think it is the usual: $\;T^t(\phi)(v):=\phi(Tv)\;$ and thus $\;T^t\in U^*\;$ . BTW, it is very common to find mistakes, and even very basic and deep ones, in the Schaum's series books...which, otoh, are very helpful books.